# Op-Amp transient modeling

Tags: operational-amplifier, transient, steady-state

Imagine I have an op-amp in a standard non-inverting configuration with the gain formula \$G=V_{in}(1+R2/R1)\$. I would like to dynamically adjust this gain by using an FPGA controlled switch to switch in and out a resistor in parallel with R2, therefore lowering and raising the gain.

My question is to how to estimate the transients that the op-amp would create? What datasheet parameters would be useful in estimating those? From what I understand, the op-amp equations (V+=V-, feedback formula, etc) are steady state equations and don't apply to transient analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an "analogue switch" and feed it from the same supply as the op-amp, you shouldn't have a problem with output transients from the op-amp. This is a tried and tested way of controlling gain on an op-amp circuit.

You need to locate a "switch" with low enough on resistance so that it doesn't significantly affect the value of R2 it is placed in series with. You can use several combinations of switches and different values of R2 to create several different gains also.

Comment: If we assume that the switch is ideal, how long will it take for the output to reach Vo=Vin(1+Rnew/R1)? How will output transition from Vo before switching to Vo after switching?

Comment: @Yuriy how good is the op-amp on slew rate? It's an op-amp slew rate problem first - you'll always be able to find an analogue switch a bit faster in operation than an op-amp. You could always have two op-amps set to different gains and use an A-switch to toggle between them for changes of gain.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion about 2 op-amps. In my application it is not possible (the input to the OP-AMP is a $600 PMT module). As to the slew rate, in my understanding it is the maximum rate of change of the output per second. While I understand that it will help predict how quickly the output returns to normal, I am trying to understand what happens to the output before it settles.